# NOT NULL constraint failed: cars_car.owner_id

Tags: django, django-forms

I was able to render the form onto the html, input data and submit it but i got a NOT NULL constraint failure. Isn't the owner assigned to its respective owners when as i have indicated in my views? i do not know what is wrong here please help!

---

**Models**

```
class Car(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    model = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField()
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=upload_image_path, null=True, blank=True)
    created = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateField(auto_now_add=False)
    mileage = models.IntegerField()
    open_market_value = models.DecimalField(max_digits=12, decimal_places=2)
    depreciation = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    down_payment = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    road_tax = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2)
    installment = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2)
    objects = models.Manager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

**Views**

```
class CarCreate(CreateView):
    model = Car
    fields = [
        'name', 'model', 
        'description', 'image', 
        'updated', 'mileage', 
        'open_market_value', 'depreciation', 
        'down_payment', 'road_tax', 
        'installment']
    template_name = 'cars/create_car.html'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.created_by = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

**HTML**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% block content %}

    <!-- Default form contact -->
<form action="{% url 'cars:create' %}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   {% csrf_token %}
   {{form | crispy}}
    <input type="submit" value="save">
</form>
<!-- Default form contact -->
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your model has a foreign key to the User model from 'django.auth'. While you are trying to save the object of 'Car' model as there was no object mentioned for the 'owner' field of the model, it is showing the error. So, you might want to explicitly mention it.

You can do something like this. Assuming that you have 'CarForm', a model form for you 'Car' model.

```
user = request.user
car_form = CarForm(request.POST)

if car_form.is_valid():
    car = car_form.save(False)
    car.owner = user
    car.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely because `owner` is a required field in your model `Car` but you have not included it in the `fields` in your `CreateView`.